# Angular.js - Appending Element From Controller

Tags: angularjs, svg, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm new to Angular, so I apologize in advance if my approach isn't idiomatic.  I'm trying to append a `<circle>` element within the `placeShot()` function found in the controller, which is called from `ng-click='placeShot($event)`.

I'm also currently hard-coding the width of `#basketball-container` within `ng-init`.  Since my page is responsive I'd like to grab the width of this element (which will be different on various devices) and then create the `<svg>` #basketball-court based on this value.

**HTML**

```
 <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div id="basketball-container" ng-controller="BasketballCtrl" ng-init="width=400; height=width*0.75">
        <h3>Width: {{width}}, Height: {{height}} - Hardcoded</h3>
        <svg id="basketball-court" ng-attr-height="{{height}}" ng-attr-width="{{width}}" ng-click="placeShot($event)">
            <!-- Boundary -->
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="{{height}}" class="boundary" />
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="{{width}}" y2="0" class="boundary" />
            <line x1="0" y1="{{height}}" x2="{{width}}" y2="{{height}}" class="boundary" />
            <line x1="{{width}}" y1="0" x2="{{width}}" y2="{{height}}" class="boundary" />
            <!-- 3 Pt Arc -->
            <path d="M {{0.11*width}} 0 V {{0.1*height}}" />
            <path d="M {{0.89*width}} 0 V {{0.1*height}}" />    
            <path d="M {{0.11*width}} {{0.1*height}} C {{0.11*width}} {{height}}, {{0.89*width}} {{height}}, {{0.89*width}} {{0.1*height}}" fill="transparent"/>
            <!-- Key Outline -->
            <path d="M {{0.35*width}} 0 v {{0.57*height}} h {{0.3*width}} v -{{0.57*height}}" fill="transparent"/>
            <!-- Top of Key -->
            <circle cx="{{width/2}}" cy="{{0.57*height}}" r="{{0.15*width}}" fill="transparent" />
            <!-- Backboard -->
            <path d="M {{0.41*width}} {{0.033*height}} h {{0.18*width}}" />
            <!-- Basket -->
            <circle cx="{{width/2}}" cy="{{0.08*height}}" r="{{0.03*width}}" fill="transparent" />

        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Angular**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('BasketballCtrl', ['$scope', '$element', function($scope, $element) {
    $scope.placeShot = function(event) {
        var x = event.offsetX;
        var y = event.offsetY

        console.log($element);
        console.log(x);
        console.log(y);

        var html = '<circle cx="'+ x.toString() +'" cy="'+ y.toString() +'" r="10" class="shot" />';
        console.log(html);

        // Append shot to <svg>
        $("#basketball-court").append(html);
    };
}]);
```

Here's a link to the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Abundnce10/426LX/6/

My original question was: How do I append a `<circle>` element within the `placeShot()` function?  But I'd be happy to hear how I should restructure my code to fall more in line with Angular best practices.

Basically, I have a page that's responsive, so I'd like to grab the width of the `<svg>`'s parent element and then allow that value to drive the sizing of it.  I'd also like to allow the user to click on the court, upon which a new `<circle>` element would mark that sport.  It seems like a simple task but I'm having trouble doing it with Angular.  I welcome all advice/feedback.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, to create the circle in js, you would normally do it like this:

```
 var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
 circle.setAttribute("cx",x);
 circle.setAttribute("cy",y);
 circle.setAttribute("r",10);
 circle.setAttribute("class","shot");
 document.getElementById('basketball-court').appendChild(circle);
```

With angular, we can just do this for the html:

```
<circle class="shot" ng-repeat="circle in circles" 
    ng-attr-cx="{{circle.x}}" 
    ng-attr-cy="{{circle.y}}" 
    ng-attr-r= "{{circle.r}}">
</circle>
```

And then for your controller:

```
$scope.circles = [];
$scope.placeShot = function(event) {
    $scope.circles.push({'x': event.offsetX, 'y': event.offsetY, 'r':10});
};
```

And actually, anywhere you an svg element with an attribute with angular variables in it (like `cx={{whatever}}`) you need to prepend `ng-attr-` to the attribute (`ng-attr-cx`) or you'll get tons of errors in the console and it won't work on some browsers.

To set the height and width, in your controller you could do:

```
 $scope.width = $('#basketball-container').width();
 $scope.height = $('#basketball-container').height();
```

If you need to resize it when the window changes, you could do

```
$(window).on('resize', function() { 
    $scope.$apply(function() { 
        $scope.width = $('#basketball-container').width();
        $scope.height = $('#basketball-container').height();
    });
 });
```

which I don't know how angular-ish that is, but it would work.

Comment: This approach makes a lot more sense.  How would you suggest I create the <svg> (and corresponding shapes) with the width of its parent element?

Answer (score 0):

A general rule in Angular is to never do DOM manipulation from a controller. All DOM manipulation should occur in a directive. So, you want to avoid adding an element in your controller method.

You should instead manipulate the $scope in your controller and let a directive update the DOM accordingly. If you set it up correctly, the DOM manipulation will happen automatically when angular runs a digest cycle. This is the beauty of angular. Using directives, you don't have to write the code that actually manipulates the DOM. You change the model and the view just updates. Here's a quick example...

```
myApp.controller('BasketballCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.ballIsVisible = false;

    $scope.placeShot = function (event) {
        $scope.ballIsVisible = true;
    }
}

<circle ng-if="ballIsVisible" />
```

Angular will continuously $watch the value of ballIsVisible and it will add the circle to the page when its true and remove it when its false. You can do just about anything with the built-in directives, or write your own. ng-if adds/removes the element, ng-show hides and shows it, ng-class adds and removes classes, etc.